# Integral of $\int \frac{\sin(x)dx}{3-\cos(x)}$

Tags: integration, trigonometry

I am trying to solve this integral and I need your suggestions.
I don't know if its OK to set $3-\cos(x)$ as $t$ $\rightarrow dt = \sin(x)dx$ or just take $\cos(x)$ and set it as $t$
$$\int \frac{\sin(x)dx}{3-\cos(x)}$$
Thanks

Comment: When you just write out function names like that, $\TeX$ interprets that as a juxtaposition of variable names and formats it accordingly. To get the appropriate font and spacing, you can use predefined commands like `\cos`, or, if you need an operator name for which there isn't a predefined command, you can use `\operatorname{name}`.

Comment: good to know. I will use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, making a substitution is the way to go, if you let $t=3-\text{cos}(x)$ then we have $dt=\text{sin(x)}dx$ which implies we have$$\int\frac{\text{sin}(x)}{3-\text{cos}(x)}dx=\int\frac{\text{sin}(x)}{t}\frac{dt}{\text{sin}(x)}=\int\frac{1}{t}dt$$I think you can continue from here.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: if $\,f\,$ is a derivable function, then

$$\int\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}dx=\log|f(x)|+C(=\text{ a constant})$$